# how to prevent logic trimming

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to make a `verilog` code for `rsa cryptosystem` the basic structure of the modules is like the code shown below.

Althogh the code works fine in simulation it gives the warnings:

```
Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <out_en> (without init value) has a constant value of 1 in block <o1>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
and Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <aa_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <test1>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

I am using xilinx ise 13.1.

please help me

```
 module okletssee(
input en,

input clk,

input[2:0] a,b,

output reg[2:0] c,

output reg out_en
    );

always @(posedge clk)

begin

if(en==1'b1)
 begin

c=a+b;

out_en=1'b1;

end

else out_en=1'b0;

end

endmodule

module test1(

input[2:0] a,b,

input clk,

output reg[2:0] out_reg
    );


wire[2:0] cc;

     wire out1_en;

     reg[2:0] aa,bb;

     reg en;

okletssee o1(en,clk,aa,bb,cc,out1_en);

reg cse;

always @(posedge clk)

begin

case(cse)

default: begin

        aa=a;

        bb=b;

        en=1'b1;

        cse=1'b1;

        end

1'b1: begin

        if(out1_en==1'b1)

        out_reg=cc;

        else cse=1'b1;

        end

endcase 

end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok... your code is really poor. The logic is completely messed up; there's no way it could simulate "fine". Your first obvious problem is that `test1.en` actually **is**  held high, and so is redundant. Which is exactly what your synthesiser is telling you.

Comment: this is not my original code . this is actually the simplified format of my code. i got rid of the errors by simply using a reset. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the output to be trimmed you should use it somehow. For example in another module or as a output pin.